# Strange compiler behavior

Tags: c++, floating-point, g++

I just hit a strange behavior when compiling a small C++ program with g++ (4.6.3). Compare the two floats celsius and test:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    float fahrenheit = 0;
    float celsius = 0;
    float test = 0;

    cout << "Temperature in °F: " << endl;
    cin >> fahrenheit;

    celsius = 5 / 9 * (fahrenheit - 32);
    test =  5 * (fahrenheit - 32) / 9;

    cout << "\nWrong:\t" << fahrenheit << " °F = " << celsius << " °C" << endl;
    cout << "Correct:" << fahrenheit << " °F = " << test << " °C" << endl;
}
```

I compiled this with just "g++ test.cpp -o test".

This is the output of the program:

```
$ ./test
Temperature in °F: 
1000

Wrong:  1000 °F = 0 °C
Correct:1000 °F = 537.778 °C
```

Can someone explain to me why g++ does (reproducibly) compute celsius to 0, whereas test contains the correct solution? Does it have anything to do with some optimization, although I didn't set any args for that? Or is this really a bug in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`5 / 9` = 0

0 * anything = 0

When you divide to integers, you get an integer back.   You can just say `5.0 / 9` and it should be a lot better.

When you're writing code and don't get what you expect, your first inclination should be "what dod **I** do wrong?" not "what did the compiler do wrong?"

It'll help you look in the right place most of the time.

Comment: Yep, that nails it. Thanks!

Comment: it's a very common mistake.. mostly for beginners, but it bites me in the butt from time to time still..  If this solved your question, please accept it as the answer by clicking the checkbox to the left of it.   If you think it was a good answer, you can click the up arrow, too.